# Using functional options instead of method

Tags: go

I tried the below, and it worked well:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type T interface {
}

type hashMap struct {
    m    map[T]T
    k    []T
}

func (h *hashMap) From(m map[T]T) {
    h.m = m
    h.k = make([]T, len(m))
    i := 0
    for key := range m {
        h.k[i] = key
        i++
    }
}

func main() {
    inv := new(hashMap)
    inv.From(map[T]T{"first": 1})
    fmt.Printf("%v", inv)
}
```

The output was correct as expected:

```sh
&{map[first:1] [first]}
```

I'm looking for a way where I can write:

```golang
inv := new(hashMap).from(map[T]T{"first": 1})
// instead of:
//  inv := new(hashMap)
//  inv.From(map[T]T{"first": 1})
```

So, I re-wrote the code as below:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type T interface {
}

type hashMap struct {
    m    map[T]T
    k    []T
    from func(m map[T]T) hashMap    // <---- new
} 

func from(m map[T]T) hashMap {        // <----- change of func signature
    h := new(hashMap)
    h.m = m
    h.k = make([]T, len(m))
    i := 0
    for key := range m {
        h.k[i] = key
        i++
    }
    return *h
}

func main() {
    inv := new(hashMap).from(map[T]T{"first": 1})
    fmt.Printf("%v", inv)
}
```

But I got the below output:

```sh
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x49c2c2]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    d:/goplay/hashmap.go:55 +0xf2
exit status 2
```

Any idea how to get it done the way I'm looking for?

Comment: `hashMap.from` is nil (the default value). The `from` func you have is not a method on `hashMap`. You need to either change the function signature back, or assign a valid func to an individual instance of `hashMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to getting it! First, since you already create the hashMap in `main()` you don't need to create again in `from()`.  Just delete line 14 and change the signature of `from()` like this:

```
func (h *hashMap) from(m map[T]T) hashMap {
```

Also delete line 11 - in Go you don't need to declare a method of a type just define it.

[Try it in the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2pjjNNx9jGm)

Also it's idiomatic to build a slice using append:

```
func (h *hashMap) from(m map[T]T) hashMap {
    h.m = m
    h.k = make([]T, 0, len(m))
    for key := range m {
        h.k = append(h.k, key)
    }
    return *h
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for the update about `append`